# Is a real-time multiplayer game using Google App Engine feasible?

Tags: google-app-engine, multiplayer, cloud-hosting

I am currently developing a real-time multiplayer game, and have been evaluating various cloud-based hosting solutions. I am unsure whether App Engine fits my needs, and would be grateful for any feedback.

In essence, I want the system to work like this: Player A calculates round n, and generates a hash out of the game state at the end of that round. He then sends his commands for that round, and the hash, as a http POST to the server. Player B does the same thing, in parallel.

The server, while handling the POST from a player, first writes the received hash code to the memcache. If the hash from the other player is not yet in the memcache, it waits and periodically checks the memcache for the other players hash. As soon as both hashes are in the memcache, it compares them for equality. If they are equal, the server sends the commands of each player to the respectively other one as the http response.

A round like that should last around half a second, meaning two requests per player per second.

Of course, this way of doing it will only work if there are at least two instances of the application running, as two requests must be dealt with in parallel. Also, the memory cache must be consistent over all instances, be fairly reliable, and update immediately.

I cannot use XMPP because I want my game to be able to run within restricted networks, so it has to be limited to http on port 80.

Is there a way to enforce that two instances of the app are always running? Are there glaringly obvious flaws in my design? Do you think an architecture like this might work on App Engine? If not, what cloud based solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this could work.  The key API for you to learn about / test would probably be the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html#Life_of_a_Typical_Channel_Message).  That is what would allow back and forth communication between the client and server.

The next issue to worry about would be memcache.  In general, it is reliable, but in the strictest sense we are supposed to assume that memcached data could disappear at any time.

If you decide that you can't risk losing the data like that, then you need to persist it in the datastore, which means you will have to experiment to make sure you can sustain 2 moves per turn.  I think this is possible, but not trivially so.  If you had said 1 move every 3 seconds I would say "no problem."  But multiple updates to one entity per second start to bump up against the practical limit on writes per second, especially if they are transactional.

Having multiple instances running will not be a problem - you can pay to keep instances warm if necessary.